# How to efficiently sort a list of firestore documents based on one value contained in each document?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Given that I have x documents that all contain a key-value pair containing information on when the document was created (something like time:2021-05-06(timestamp)), how would I sort the documents in ascending order as quickly as possible?

I am using javascript and firebase firestore.

My code so far looks like this:

```
const docs = await getDocs(
    collection(db, "users", auth.currentUser.uid, "valkompass")
  );
// sort docs
```

Comment: That should actually be fairly basic: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data
Did you try something like that already: `query(collection(db, "users", auth.currentUser.uid, "valkompass"), orderBy("timestamp", "desc"))`?

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @Frank , you can sort documents in ascending order by using the `orderBy()` method. See sample code below:

```
const q = query(collection(db, "users"), orderBy("timestamp", "desc"));

const docs = await getDocs(q);
docs.forEach((doc) => {
  // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

---

For more information, you may check [**Order and limit data**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data).